# GPG keyserver says my key is not public

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I have created a GPG key with `gpg --gen-key`, accepted all the default options. 
I do `gpg --list-keys` and receive:

```
C:/Users/Myname/AppData/Roaming/gnupg/pubring.gpg
pub   2048R/B296038B 2015-11-10
uid       [ uneing.] my name <myname@gmail.com>
sub   2048R/E86C0F4D 2015-11-10
```

I then do `gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-keys B296038B`.

The keyserver answers with (translated from german, not literal):

```
keyserver filetransfer error: not a public key
Sending to keyserver failed: not a public key
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought I had created a public and a secret key. 
I also tried adding  `sub   12345R/E86C0F4D` which failed with the same error.

**EDIT:** I edited in the original values. This was ran on Windows with [gpg4win](http://www.gpg4win.org/). I ran exactly the same process on an Ubuntu machine and everything went fine, so this is perhaps a bug in gpg4win.

Comment: Please don't overobfuscate your questions. For example, your key size is hardly something that can distinguish you. Additionally, it is good practice to at least use values that are allowed as input, `XXXXXXXX` is no valid key ID (built from hex digits), `DEADBEEF` would be a canonical example in the allowed alphabet and is widely recognized as an example value.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with the key ID you provide. As you don't provide the actual command line you executed, I can't exactly describe what the wrong output was. Likely you used something like `1234R/XXXXXXXX` to define the key to work with, which is not understood by GnuPG.

An example with my key: for the key

```
$ gpg --list-keys a4ff2279
pub   8192R/AA4FF2279 2012-12-25
[...]
```

run

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-keys a4ff2279
```

while capitalization of the key ID is not relevant. Generally, usage of short key IDs is strongly disrecommended because of [possible collision attacks](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/74009/19837). [Use long key IDs instead](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/84280/19837).